# How to add Maven to an existing IntelliJ Android project

Tags: java, android, maven

I've been doing some research on adding Maven to an existing Android project and I'm struggling to see how this works.  I've used Maven once at work on a web based project with Netbeans, but for this project I'm looking to use IntelliJ.  I can create a new "Maven Module", but I already have an Android project so I'm not entirely sure that's the route I should be taking.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452771/is-it-possible-to-setup-intellij-android-project-to-work-with-maven) which does provide some detail, but not a step-by-step windows integration guide (at least that I'm seeing).

Is it possible for me to use Maven within an Android project?

**Edit:** I'm looking to do this within a Windows environment

Comment: Are you trying to automagically create a POM for your existing project, or just activate the IDE's Maven-specific functionality?

Comment: @TomG - I'm not entirely sure.  I've only used Maven once and intend on using it with this project.  Whatever I need to use it is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: In that case, refer to @kctang's answer. It's really more important to correctly create the POM, and then use the IDE to create its own configuration based off of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question in the last sentence: Yes, you can use Maven to build an Android project.

You should use the maven-android-plugin in your Maven project. The best place to get started is https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted. Need to read up a bit, but definitely worth the effort.

If I have existing IDE specific Android project that you would like to switch to Maven, instead of trying to "add Maven support to an existing IntelliJ project", I would:

1. Create a new Maven based project using an appropriate archetype https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes
2. Copy existing source/resources to the Maven project directories.

If done correctly, you can open this (Android) Maven project (pom.xml) in IntelliJ and use it like an Android project (including GUI editor). IntelliJ automatically generates an IntelliJ project from Maven's pom.xml and detects the Android facet.

This way, your project also stays IDE agnostic - you can do everything (build/test/deploy) from command line as well - how Maven projects should be IMHO. :D

Comment: I'm trying to do steps 1 and 2 as you mention, but that URL isn't working for me right now :-\

Comment: I've updated maven archetypes link. Strangely, that link was working few days ago.

Comment: The documentation available at that link appears to contain a lot of linux commands but no Windows instructions.  Do you know of any resources for Windows?

Comment: @Webnet Sorry, I can't help with windows specific environment. Most of the commands should be OS independent (i.e. mvn goals) or very basic linux path/commands (i.e. rm to remove files/dirs) that you should be able to figure out.